# Simple questions about Polymer

Tags: polymer

I begin using Polymer. It is great thing. Thanks to all conributors.

I have core-menu and core-pages elements.

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>
    <core-menu selected="0" id="core_menu">
      <core-item on-tap="{{sel_brosh}}" label="Broshura"></core-item>
      <core-item on-tap="{{sel_list}}" label="Listovka"></core-item>
    </core-menu>
    <core-pages selected="0" id="sec_pages">
      <section id="sec_brosh">Page One</section>
      <section id="sec_list">Page Two</section>
    </core-pages>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-element', {
      sel_brosh: function () { this.$.sec_pages.selected = "0"; },
      sel_list: function () { this.$.sec_pages.selected = "1"; },
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

It work as i want, but i think it is not 'best practice'. How can i make it with one function? I try to get value this.$.core_menu.selected, but i get only old value.

May be i chose a wrong way. I want get a few "pages" with simple menu which switching pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <core-menu selected="{{selected}}">
      <core-item label="Broshura"></core-item>
      <core-item label="Listovka"></core-item>
    </core-menu>
    <core-pages selected="{{selected}}">
      <section>Page One</section>
      <section>Page Two</section>
    </core-pages>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      selected: 0
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

ProTip: the MVC concept of Polymer is that the `my-element` has a data-model that informs it's children. I mention this because it's easy to look at this and say oh, `core-menu` and `core-pages` are data-bound, but the better description is that `core-menu` and `core-pages` are data-bound to `my-element`. The host, `my-element`, is in control (hence *controller* [or maybe more precisely *presenter* in an MVP pattern]) and the children don't interact with each other directly.